# Error al correr laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Help with the following error in laravel

```
 Fatal Error: Class 'lluminate\Foundation\Application' no found in boostrap/app.php on line 14
```

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what how you got to this error, what you think it might be and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your file composer.json

```
en "config":{"preferred-install": "dist", "secure-http:false" }
```

and run   composer update